# Accessing a PHP variable after I call the header function

Tags: php, variables, header, session-variables

I am having a bit of trouble with accessing a PHP variable after I use the header function. I have a variable, patient_id, which is POSTED from a form. It is then been used to check if a record exists in a database. If it does, then I am creating a SESSION and redirecting the page to the top, using the header function. It then runs the code in the if statement that requires a SESSION to be created. Is it possible to access the variable, $patient_id?? Thanks

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['patient'])){
   echo($patient_id);
}else{
    $patient_id = $_POST['patient_id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `patient` WHERE `patient_id`='$patient_id'";
    $query_run = mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

    if($num == 1){
    $_SESSION['patient'] = true;
    header('Location:trial.php');
    exit();
}else{


}
?>
```

Comment: You're trying to `echo($patient_id);` before you assigned it...

Comment: Also, you can't have an `else` statement follow another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should be using mysqli or better PDO as mysql_ has been deprecated. But this should solve your problem.

```
    <?php

            if(isset($_SESSION['patient'])){

               echo($_SESSION['patient_id']);

            }else{

                $patient_id = $_POST['patient_id'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `patient` WHERE `patient_id`='$patient_id'";
                $query_run = mysql_query($query);

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {

                    $_SESSION['patient'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['patient_id'] = $row['patient_id'];
                    header('Location:trial.php');

                }
            }
?>
```